# Mechanism of oxidation reaction with periodate

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-oxidation

What is the mechanism of reaction of periodate with β-hydroxy amine? I tried the to write the mechanism similar to that of reaction with 1,2-diol but I am not able to obtain 2 carbonyl compound and like that in case of diol neither evolution of ammonia.

Here's my work:

[image]

Comment: Your mechanism is good but you need to remember that the imine product you have drawn will hydrolyse to the carbonyl compound in acidic conditions as you are using periodic acid and there is water present.

Comment: Yeah right I didnt think of that thanks